# Search particular data from external API in laravel

Tags: laravel, http, search

Want to fetch data from external API using laravel

I am new to Laravel and I want to search the data from external API (given below) by name.

This is blade view for search:

```
 <form method="get" action="{{route('search')}}">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search meals">
     <button type="submit">search</button>
  </form>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/search', 'App\Http\Controllers\searchController@search')->name('search');
```

Controller function

```
 public function search(Request $request)
{
    $request->input('search');
    $meal = Http::get('www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${search}')->json();
    dd($meal);
}
```

This is the API from which I want to fetch the data by name (strMeal):

```
{
"meals": [
    {
        "idMeal": "52771",
        "strMeal": "Spicy Arrabiata Penne",
        "strDrinkAlternate": null,
        "strCategory": "Vegetarian",
        "strArea": "Italian",
        "strInstructions": "Bring a large pot of water to a boil. Add kosher salt to the boiling water, then add the pasta. Cook according to the package instructions, about 9 minutes.\r\nIn a large skillet over medium-high heat, add the olive oil and heat until the oil starts to shimmer. Add the garlic and cook, stirring, until fragrant, 1 to 2 minutes. Add the chopped tomatoes, red chile flakes, Italian seasoning and salt and pepper to taste. Bring to a boil and cook for 5 minutes. Remove from the heat and add the chopped basil.\r\nDrain the pasta and add it to the sauce. Garnish with Parmigiano-Reggiano flakes and more basil and serve warm.",
        "strMealThumb": "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/ustsqw1468250014.jpg",
        "strTags": "Pasta,Curry",
        "strYoutube": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IszT_guI08",
        "strIngredient1": "penne rigate",
        "strIngredient2": "olive oil",
        "strIngredient3": "garlic",
        "strIngredient4": "chopped tomatoes",
        "strIngredient5": "red chile flakes",
        "strIngredient6": "italian seasoning",
        "strIngredient7": "basil",
        "strIngredient8": "Parmigiano-Reggiano",
        "strIngredient9": "",
        "strIngredient10": "",
        "strIngredient11": "",
        "strIngredient12": "",
        "strIngredient13": "",
        "strIngredient14": "",
        "strIngredient15": "",
        "strIngredient16": null,
        "strIngredient17": null,
        "strIngredient18": null,
        "strIngredient19": null,
        "strIngredient20": null,
        "strMeasure1": "1 pound",
        "strMeasure2": "1/4 cup",
        "strMeasure3": "3 cloves",
        "strMeasure4": "1 tin ",
        "strMeasure5": "1/2 teaspoon",
        "strMeasure6": "1/2 teaspoon",
        "strMeasure7": "6 leaves",
        "strMeasure8": "spinkling",
        "strMeasure9": "",
        "strMeasure10": "",
        "strMeasure11": "",
        "strMeasure12": "",
        "strMeasure13": "",
        "strMeasure14": "",
        "strMeasure15": "",
        "strMeasure16": null,
        "strMeasure17": null,
        "strMeasure18": null,
        "strMeasure19": null,
        "strMeasure20": null,
        "strSource": null,
        "strImageSource": null,
        "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": null,
        "dateModified": null
    }
]
}
```

Result

After Dump it displays null array

[image]

Comment: did you type in a meal? if you did what did you type

Answer (score 0):

I tried this via GuzzleHTTP

Blade Template Search

```
<form action="{{ route('search.submit') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="">Search</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Then for the Post Request Controller Function

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;    
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $url = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=";
    $search_query = $url . $request->s;
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', $search_query);
    echo $response->getBody();
}
```

Response i got....
[image]

Comment: Its not working properly, I want to get result according to my searched word..